# How do you copy notes from a Microsoft CRM workflow?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm

I have a workflow that runs upon the change of status of an entity (Opportunity "Won"), in which I am creating another entity.

I want to copy all the notes from the Opportunity to the new entity, but I cannot see how to do it.

Is this possible without coding (or in fact, with coding!)

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible without coding.  With coding (custom workflow activity and the ICrmService) you can read and creates notes (Entity: annotation).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with benjynito answer. You need to hook a custom workflow activity in order to get the notes object.

Here is the link to setup a basic custom workflow activity : http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=CustomWorkflowActivity

An example of some custom activities on CodePlex: http://crm4activities.codeplex.com/

Custom workflow activity documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151142.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using the clone children action in "[Dynamics 365 Workflow Tools](https://github.com/demianrasko/Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools)". I used this library to copy the notes from a lead to an account when the lead is qualified. For exact steps see the documentation of [clone children](https://github.com/demianrasko/Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools/blob/master/docs/Clone%20Children.md) or my blog post [Copying Notes from a Lead to an Account](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2019/01/copying-notes-from-lead-to-account.html) that shows you how I did it for notes.